# Plural form of "malware"

Tags: usage

I'm writting a cybersecurity essay about malware.
I searched on [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/malwares) and found that "malware" is uncountable. So, the plural form of "malware" is "malware".

I was wondering if this usage of "malware" is correct:
 
*"Nowedays, malware **are** more and more sophisticated"*

Comment: As @Neil says, 'malware' derived from 'software' is a mass noun, always taking the singular. As you're writing about IT, forgive me for reminding you that 'code' is also a mass noun, despite far too many examples of its misuse as a plural on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally uncountable nouns in english are treated as singular, even if there is more than one.  "All the software is corrupted" or "All this flour is heavy!"  Malware is not really considered countable since it isn't really referring to a number of installations but more of an abstract concept.  If you meant to say that the different malware *programs* are more and more sophisticated, you could do so, because then you're referring to "programs" which *is* countable.

This as opposed to *countable* nouns which *are* treated as singular or plural, even when the plural form is irregular.  "All the sheep look sick" or "The moose all have thick fur"